# Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, closures, anonymous

I am learning more about closures, and I want to re-create something similar to Laravel's route function.

SO i have the following code:

```html
<?php



Class Foo{


    public static function show($second, $third){

        return "First " . $second . $third;

    }

}


echo $my_var = Foo::show("Second ", function(){

    return "Third ";

});
```

but if I run it, I get "Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string " error.

If I remove the variable $third from the Foo::show function, theres no errors given, but of course i dont see the third variable.

I was expecting result : First Second Third;

What gives ? I am just learning.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$third` is a **function**, to get it's returned value - you **must** call it. Function call is usually done with `()`, so the change is:

```
return "First " . $second . $third();
```

Here, function passed as `$third` argument is executed, string `Third` returned and concatenated with previous string.

Comment: Amazing ! Never thought about it this way, yet it so simple now haha. Thanks a lot man !

Comment: Done :)  but votes are not publicly displayed until i get more reputation i think :)